# Translucent/Tansparent status bar and navigation bar

Tags: android

I would like to have the statusbar and the navigationbar Translucent on my Main activity, while all the other activities use the Material Design.

What I got so far is this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
}
```

But the result is:

[image]

I even tried to set the color to transparent:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    window.setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
}
```

But I don't get the graduated shading I'm looking for to make the navigation buttons and the icons on the status bar visible:

[image]

Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I went around the problem.

I created a drawable that simulates the shade I was looking for and put it as wallpaper, while making the status bar and navigation bar transparent:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    Drawable background = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    window.setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    window.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From Android Lollipop it is fully translucent, without any shade. So you should do a color like #33000000 to get a shade in the statusbar.

**Edit**

I think you can only set a color for the statusbar. But you can add an ImageView with a gradient drawable and only show it when you're on lollipop. The status bar is 25dp high. I think there is also an attribute for this, but I don't know it. This way you simulate a gradient in the statusbar.

Comment: #33000000 just gives me a more transparent status bar (13% transparency of the full black), not the graduate shade I'm looking for.

Comment: @Jones this is what you use on lollipop: `window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));` which is fully transparent (#00000000) my answer is indeed 13% transparency on black which gives a shade. Is that not what you meant?

Comment: No, I'm looking for a gradual shade, the one we can see on the "desktop".

Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @Jones like KitKat you mean right? I think you can only set the color. But you can add an `ImageView` with a gradient drawable and only show it when you're on lollipop. The status bar is 25dp high. I think there is also an attribute for this, but I don't know it

Comment: Yeah, I meant that, ultimately I left the bars transparent and put a wallpaper that simulate the shade, since you can't put a drawable background for the statusbar nor the actionbar.

Comment: I meant the same, but my idea was two ImageViews. Also works good. Could you at least upvote my answer?